# Update value in struct not working

Tags: go, struct

i’ve struct with value and I run with loop to update value, while debug the code
I see that it enter to the case lines like `element.Type = "cccc”` but after the loop exit when I look 
at ftr the old value exist and its not updated, what am I missing here ?

```
ftr := FTR{}

err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlFile), &ftr)

for index, element := range ftr.Mod{

    switch element.Type {
    case “aaa”, “bbbb”:
        element.Type = "cccc”
    case "htr”:
        element.Type = "com"
    case "no":
        element.Type = "jnodejs"
    case "jdb”:
        element.Type = "tomcat"
    }

}
```

This is the struct

```
type FTR struct {
    Id            string     
    Mod      []Mod  
}


type Mod struct {
    Name       string
    Type       string
}
```

Comment: What is `ftr`, and where is it's type declaration?

Comment: @JimB give me a min and I update the question

Comment: @JimB - I've added the structs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use pointers:

```
type FTR struct {
    Id  string
    Mod []*Mod
}
```

Or address your items directly

```
for i := range ftr.Mod {
    switch ftr.Mod[i].Type {
    case "aaa", "bbbb":
        ftr.Mod[i].Type = "cccc"
    case "htr":
        ftr.Mod[i].Type = "com"
    case "no":
        ftr.Mod[i].Type = "jnodejs"
    case "jdb":
        ftr.Mod[i].Type = "tomcat"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i've close the question , What is the preferred direction , option 1 or two, for your POV

Comment: @Ninawatcher: pointers allow for more flexibility, especially if you need to differentiate between and empty string and no setting at all. Either way is fine depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

While rangin over elements you get a copy of the element. Thats why changing it doesn't change original value.

You may iterate over indices and change elements. And you do not need change slice to pointers:

```
type FTR struct {
    Id       string     
    Mod      []Mod  
}

for index := range ftr.Mod{
    switch ftr.Mod[index].Type {
    case “aaa”, “bbbb”:
        ftr.Mod[index].Type = "cccc”
    case "htr”:
        ftr.Mod[index].Type = "com"
    case "no":
        ftr.Mod[index].Type = "jnodejs"
    case "jdb”:
        ftr.Mod[index].Type = "tomcat"
    }

}
```